# Keep transforming elements on top of other elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, css, z-index, transform

I'm learning to use CSS3 3D transforms, but I'm having trouble keeping elements which are transforming on top of all other elements.

This is what I have so far: http://bos.rggwebdesigns.com/

As you can see, the site follows standard z-index rules for the hierarchy of the three .row divs, meaning that cards in the first row are behind the card in the second row and so on.

I tried adding lines to the transform script (in main.js) which selects the .row element above the clicked .card element and sets its z-index to 1000, however that doesn't seem to work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.card').click(function() {
        $('.row').removeClass('top');
        $('.card').not(this).removeClass('flipped');
        $(this).parents().eq(2).toggleClass('top');
        $(this).toggleClass('flipped');
    })
});
```

To reiterate, I'm trying to ensure that all parts of a transforming element always appear above every other element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to what I see z-index needs to be relative. So if you set the `position : relative;` for class "row" that should solve your problem.

**EDIT:**
I was reviewing your code. You also need to change `.row.top` in css to `.top`

Comment: That did it, thank you very much. It's wonderful when the answer is so simple. Also, both `.top` and `.row.top` would work in this case.